# Pullback on $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ of $\pi$ : $Z(F) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings, pullback

I am self studying some introductory algebraic geometry and the author of lecture notes make the following claim without explaining the reason.

Let $F\subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$, $Z(F)\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be the zero set of $F$, $\pi=(x_1,...,x_{n-1}): Z(F)\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$.Then

$k[x_1,...,x_n]/I(Z(F)) = \pi^{*}(k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}])\cdot [w_n]$

where $[w_n]$ is the class of $x_n$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I(Z(F))$

I have no idea how he get this. It looks right because $k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ is regular on $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ and if I pull it back it is regular on $Z(F)$ but without containing $x_n$. But  I can not quite see why RHS and LHS are equal.

Comment: In words: the (somewhat informal) process of adjoining an element $a$ to a ring $R$ which is algebraically dependent on elements of $R$ is the same as the (formally rigorous) two-step process of 1) adjoining a transcendental element $a$ and 2) modding out by a polynomial in $R[a]$ that encodes the definition of $a$ from the first process. I would be angry at your professors if you hadn't learned something to this effect in your first course on ring theory.

Comment: Does this answer my question? I do not quite see why I need to adjoin any transcendental element here.

Comment: I'm just referring to the indeterminate $x_n$; to connect your notation with mine, $R = k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$.